# Parsing a C++ file to a XML file

Tags: c++, xml, parsing

I am looking to find some parsers that will help me converting a C++ file that describes a test case into a XML file.

I have found one parser named GCC-XML but I didn't find any other one. I need a parser that will convert everything in my C+ file

Has someone ever used a C++ to XML parser ?

Comment: Plz check this link: [Are there parsing tools like gcc-xml for C++11 code syntax?](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/13542)

Comment: Its pleasure to help you @Anatch

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about just data members of the c++ files then I personally like using tinyXML for outputing data to an XML file. If you mean literally you want some format of your entire c++ file in an XML form then I apologize for being unable to give you a good answer. TinyXML has a pretty simple set of functions to use if that is what you're looking for, and shouldn't take more than 10 - 20 minutes to learn how to efficiently output your data.

Comment: Ok thanks for the information, yes it is the whole c++file that I want to parse.